# IAR MSP430 compiler internal error while compiling

Tags: compiler-construction, msp430, iar

IAR C/C++ Compiler for MSP430
5.10.1 [Evaluation] (5.10.1.20144)

I get an illegal state internal error when attempting to compile the FreeRTOS 5.4 Task.c file (everything else compiles fine)

Internal Error: [CoreUtil/General]: Illegal state

The kick start version of IAR (MSP430 version) works fine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try posting this on the [Yahoo hosted MSP430](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/msp430/) group.  Anders, the guy that wrote/maintains the compiler, is good at answering problems there.  There are also some very active members there who provide good answers to sensible questions.

You could also send a problem report through their [support](http://supp.iar.com/Support/Request/) system.  They have always been very good at getting me fixes to any problems.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas

- try changing the optimisation level
- do a "divide and conquer" on the problem source file until you have reduced it to the smallest amount of code that can cause the ICE, then try re-expressing this part of the code to get rid of the ICE and/or send it to IAR as a bug report
- check for updates from IAR - this may be a compiler bug that they are aware of and maybe even have a fix/workaround for

Comment: Ha! I change the optimization to high (max) and now it works. Not really a solution to the core problem, but at least gives me some breathing room time wise.